# dot product with diagonal matrix, without creating it full matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'd like to calculate a dot product of two matrices, where one of them is a diagonal matrix. However, I don't want to use `np.diag` or `np.diagflat` in order to create the full matrix, but instead use the 1D array directly filled with the diagonal values. Is there any way or numpy operation which I can use for this kind of problem?

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
y = np.arange(3) # diagonal elements
z = np.dot(x, np.diag(y))
```

and the solution I'm looking for should be without `np.diag`

```
z = x ??? y
```

Comment: Use simple multiplication with `broadcasting` : `x*y`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directly multiplying the ndarray by your vector will work. Numpy conveniently assumes that you want to multiply the nth column of x by the nth element of your y.

```
x = np.random.random((5, 5)
y = np.random.random(5)

diagonal_y = np.diag(y)
z = np.dot(x, diagonal_y)
np.allclose(z, x * y)  # Will return True
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

The Einstein summation is an elegant solution to these kind of problems:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(0,1, size=5)
w = np.random.uniform(0,1, size=(5, 3))

diagonal_x = np.diagflat(x)

z = np.dot(diagonal_x, w)

zz = np.einsum('i,ij->ij',x , w)

np.allclose(z, zz)  # Will return True
```

See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum

Comment: I didn't know of this functionality. Elegant indeed, but for the present case simple broadcasting performs ~25% faster, at least for moderate-sized arrays (up to 5000x5000).