# Multiply array with diagonal matrix stored as vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D array A = [a, b, c...] (length N_A) and a 3D array T of shape (N_A, N_B, N_A). A is meant to represent a diagonal N_A by N_A matrix.

I'd like to perform contractions of A with T without having to promote A to dense storage. In particular, I'd like to do

```
np.einsum('ij, ikl', A, T)
```

and

```
np.einsum('ikl, lm', T, A)
```

is it possible to do such things while keeping A sparse?

Note this question is similar to

[dot product with diagonal matrix, without creating it full matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152392/dot-product-with-diagonal-matrix-without-creating-it-full-matrix)

but not identical, since it's not clear to me how one generalizes to more complicated index patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.einsum('ij, ikl', np.diag(a), t)` is equivalent to `(a * t.T).T`.

`np.einsum('ikl, lm', t, np.diag(a))` is equivalent to `a * t`.

(found by trial-and-error)